# how to send email with php over my existing email account under centos

Tags: php

we have CentOS, and we want to send EMails over our existing Mail-Accounts.
The Server Script is in PHP. I use the mail() function of php, but I want to use it with the exception that it shall use an existing mail account to send mails.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a SMTP client called MSMTP which you can use to send emails using third-party SMTP servers. You can use MSMTP with PHP's mail() in the place of sendmail.

Maybe this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gmail-or-yahoo-with-php-mail-function) helps, of course you wouldn't be using gmail/yahoo for your mail server but your existing mail server.

Maybe you are just trying to set the 'from' address within mail() though?
Taken from [php.org](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```